# Does AS3 have no color/rgba support class?

Tags: actionscript-3

Easy as it is working with RGBA from a 32-bit value, most libraries I've used previously implement utilities to avoid all the bit-shifting, like an `RGBA()` macro or similar. I can't see anything like this on livedocs, perhaps it's there and I am missing it?

Using Flash 9/10, it needs to be a core AS3 class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS3 don't have such thing. Well there might be class out there.

The simplest way:

```
var d:BitmapData = new BitmapData(10,10);
var pixel:int = d.getPixel(5,5);
var red:int = pixel >> 16;
var green:int = pixel >> 8 & 0xff;
var blue:int = pixel & 0xff;
```

Here I created a BitmapData. Then get the color of point(5,5). The pixel here is RGB. Then do some shifting to get component.

For a ARGB value(Edited):

```
var argb:int = 0x11223344;
var alpha:int = argb >> 24;
var red:int = argb >> 16 & 0xff;
var green:int = argb >> 8 & 0xff;
var blue:int = argb & 0xff;
```

Comment: @MorrisLiang. Note that flash stores the color information as ARGB, not RGBA.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have not been coding AS3 for a year.

Comment: I found problems using `>>`, I had to use `>>>` which I never knew existed!

Comment: What's the problem? I have used this snippet in one of my flash app to extract the color value, and everything works fine.

Comment: The only difference between `>>` and `>>>` is how they deal with negative numbers and overflow. Type your colors as `uint` and you shouldn't need to worry about it...

Comment: @fenomas. I've just read your comment. I realize it's a week old (sorry) but anyway, I thought I'd point out that typing either the color or the component as `uint` won't help here. You have to use `>>>` or mask the result with 0xff (which will effectively discard the sign bit and the rest of the bits that were set to 1 because of the sign in the original number).

Answer (score 0):

Nope, there are no particular built-in methods to avoid bit-shifting. If you don't want to use a library, you could copy and paste some suitable functions into your code - google popped [this](http://www.flashandmath.com/intermediate/rgbs/index.html) up, and it looks suitable enough.